# How to delete a string in multiple files by using the function eraseBetween (Matlab R2019a)

Tags: matlab

I am trying without success to delete a specific string (everything between xmln= and the next space) in multiple text files (xml files) by using the Matlab function eraseBetween. The files would then be moved to a new folder. The code so far is below. Any help welcome.

```
modified_xml = fullfile(pwd, 'modified_xml')    
if exist([pwd '\modified_xml'])~=7              
    mkdir(modified_xml);                        
end
InputOldFiles = dir(fullfile('*.xml'));          
OldFilesNames = {InputOldFiles.name};            
for k = 1 : length(InputOldFiles)
    OldFiles = OldFilesNames{k};

    FID = fopen(OldFiles, 'r');
    if FID == -1, error('Cannot open file'), end

    % Delete specific string (everything between xmlns= and the next empty space)
    text = textscan(FID, '%s', 'delimiter', '\n', 'whitespace', '');
    new_text = eraseBetween(text,"xmlns="," ");
    NewFiles = fopen(OldFiles, 'w');
    if NewFiles == -1, error('Cannot open file'), end

    % Save the file 
    fprintf(NewFiles, '%s\n', new_text{:});
    fclose(NewFiles);

    % Copy the files
    copyfile(OldFiles, NewFiles);             
end
```

Comment: Okay so what problem are you facing?

Comment: my apologies: the code doesnt work. I get the following error: Error using eraseBetween (line 60)
First argument must be a string array, character vector, or cell array of character vectors.

Comment: What is `text`? (It's exact value?)

Comment: text is the text file that is being read. In the first cell of each file I need to remove the text between xmlns= and the next space

Comment: Okay but I asked for its exact value

Comment: text is a 1x1 cell containing a 1073x1 cell, each one of them corresponding to a line of text. It doesnt have a 'value' per say. I apologize if I didnt understand your question

Comment: does it work if you do `new_text = eraseBetween(text{1},"xmlns="," ");`?

Comment: Please post a minimal example, defining all variables or including a small file, so the code can be run as is

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it:

```
% Little function to edit multiple XML files
% New files are copied into the Modified_XML_Files folder
% and original files are not overwritten

% Creation of a new folder
Modified_XML_Files = fullfile(pwd, 'Modified_XML_Files')
if exist([pwd '\Modified_XML_Files'])~=7
    mkdir(Modified_XML_Files);
end

% Copy XML files and move to new folder
copyfile('*.xml', 'Modified_XML_Files')
cd Modified_XML_Files

% List of XML files to modify
XML_Files = dir(fullfile('*.xml'));
XML_Files_Names = {XML_Files.name};

% Loop and delete text between xmlns= and the next space inclusively
for k = 1 : length(XML_Files)
    Old_File = XML_Files_Names{k};
    file_text = textread(Old_File, '%s', 'delimiter', '\n', 'whitespace', '');
    file_text = eraseBetween(file_text, "xmlns=", " ", 'Boundaries', 'inclusive');
    New_File = fopen(Old_File, 'w');

    for i=1:length(file_text)
        fprintf(New_File, '%s\n', file_text{i});
    end

    New_File = fclose(New_File);
end
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56277235/edit) your answer and explain how it works and answers your question.